# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, mediapipe

**Environment**: Debian, Debian GNU/Linux, 10 (buster), amd64 built on 20210609, supports Shielded VM features.

**Platform**: Google cloud compute engine

**Python version**: Python 3.7.3

**pip3 version**: pip 18.1

**command**: pip3 install mediapipe

**result**:
Collecting mediapipe
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mediapipe

I have also tried to install it by downloading .whl file of it

**command**: pip3 install mediapipe-0.8.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

**respose**:
mediapipe-0.8.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Create a python virtual environment. Then repeat the install. Post all of the error output. Also refer to this link for manual building https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-debian-and-ubuntu

Comment: `pip3 --version` ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that mediapipe has some [Incompatibilities found with python > 3.7.0](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1325#issuecomment-841799232). There are issues with python 3.9+, or with python 32-bit (rather than 64)

My suggestion is to downgrade python version to 3.6 using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html). We will create a python environment with the suggested version 3.6:

```
$ sudo apt install wget
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh 
$ chmod +x Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ ./Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh 
$ conda install python=3.6
$ conda create --name py36 python=3.6
$ conda activate py36
$ pip install mediapipe
```

There are multiples ways to solve this, but I have reproduced in your exactly same environment and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 64-bit python. just uninstall the 32bit python and install
64-bit version of python from:

> https://www.python.org/downloads/

Maker sure to check the "Add to PATH" checkbox during installation.
After installing, you can run pip command and mediapipe will be installed smoothly.

```
pip install mediapipe
```